# Mongod doesn't recognize net.http in yaml config?

Tags: mongodb, yaml

I have the following config as mongod.cfg:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\logs\mongo.log"
    logAppend: true
storage:
    dbPath: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data\"
net:
    http:
        enabled: true
```

I'm running MongoDB 2.6.3 on Windows 7 64 bit by running: `mongod --config mongod.cfg` I'm inside the folder and I know it's parsing the correct mongod.cfg. However, I'm getting the following output:

```
Unrecognized option: net.http
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

I am pulling my hair out wondering why it's not parsing. I'm reading straight from [the configuration page on Mongo's site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and I still can't make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed spaces after the headers. It needed to be:

```
systemLog:<space>
    destination: file
    path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\logs\mongo.log"
    logAppend: true
storage:<space>
    dbPath: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data\"
net:<space>
    http:<space>
        enabled: true
```

Comment: I doubt that was actually the issue. My config file works without spaces at all.

Comment: May it be that you had a tab character at the last lite before "enabled:"? That would have caused your described behavior on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the similar issue when add auth to MongoDB admin user. When install MongoDB 3.0.8 or 3.0.15, the error appears:
CONTROL **Hotfix** kb2731284 or a later update is not installed, will zero-out files.

Fail to install kb2731284(obtained from MS's mail) in my PC whose OS is win7 enterprise version, no vaild resolution online.

**Unrecognized option: net.http

try 'mongod --help' for more information**

Then update MongoDB to v3.6 can avoid the error in the beginning, but now if want to add auth for MongoDB user using the **mongod.cfg** file, following content need to be used:

```css
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "D:\\mongodb\\log\\mongodb.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "D:\\mongodb"
   journal:
      enabled: true
   engine: wiredTiger
net:
   port: 27017
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Save the file `mongod.cfg`.
Create folder `C:\mongodb\data\`,
then create subfolder `C:\mongodbdata\log`,
Copy the mongod.cfg file to related location of MongoDB bin, such as `C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\`.

Then set value `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` in `mongod.cfg` file to true.

Open cmd.exe with the administrator privilege:

```
"C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" "--config=c:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.cfg" --auth --install
```

If the mongodb service is not running, type `net start mongodb`

```
C:\Users\{username}\Desktop>netstart mongodb
```

```css
> use admin
> db.createUser("admin", "yourpassword", roles: ["root"]})
> db.auth(user, yourpassword)
```

Restart MongoDB from commond line.
Set value `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` to `false`.

Since for MongoDB 3.6 (actually any version after v3.2) have removed the `net.http` options (**Refer**: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

Then all issues met can be completely solved.